# Cyanide inhibitor of Catalase

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry, chemical-biology

Why is it that cyanide is an inhibitor of catalase but carbon monoxide isn't?
What makes cyanide bind well to $\ce{Fe^3+}$?

Answer (score 1):

Jan has already covered this topic in a related question: [Why is the cyanide ion toxic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40968/why-is-the-cyanide-ion-toxic)

$\ce{CN-}$ and $\ce{CO}$ are isoelectronic, and one might expect them to behave exactly similarly. However, there is a key difference: the orbital energies in $\ce{CN-}$ are higher than in $\ce{CO}$, due to the lower electronegativity of $\ce{N}$ compared to $\ce{O}$.

This means that $\ce{CN-}$ is a much *better* σ donor, and a much *poorer* π acceptor than $\ce{CO}$. Consequently $\ce{CN-}$ is much happier binding to a metal in a *higher* oxidation state, whereas $\ce{CO}$ is much happier binding to a metal in a *lower* oxidation state.