# Cyanide complexes in Molecular Orbital Theory

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, coordination-compounds

In molecular orbital theory, please explain why cyanide ion combines with metal from the carbon end and not from the nitrogen end?

Comment: It can be other way round, depending on cation. Why this theory not another? You need sth more advanced then HSAB?

Comment: agree with Mith, HSAB is the best explanation imo since cyanide is ambidentate, but I guess if you just want an explanation of why it *can* coordinate via C then I suppose the shape of the HOMO would explain it. That doesn't mean it *always* coordinates via C.

Answer (score 4):

In [this answer of Martin’s](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31003), you can find a molecular orbital diagram of $\ce{CO}$. The corresponding diagram for cyanide, $\ce{CN-}$ is essentially identical, there will only be different orbital energies and very slightly different extends of the lobes.

When forming a coordinate bond to a metal centre, cyanide will primarily attack with its highest occupied molecular orbital, the HOMO, since it is a nucleophile (attacking a positively polarised metal centre). You can also see the HOMO depicted as the bottom image of the following set as taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanide):

[image: different depictions of cyanide]

Note the large lobe extending outwards on carbon’s side. An attack with this lobe is greatly preferred, hence why isocyanides are comparatively rare.