# Formal Charge in Coordinate covalent bonds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, formal-charge

I am in an honors chemistry course right now and I would like to know the formal charges of the atoms in CO, my confusion is that because the bond is partially coordinate covalent, are the bonded electrons still counted as #bonds/2 or should I count the number of electrons donated by each atom (making the formal charge 0 for both) Please help me understand and explain **WHY**not just how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: CO is a more complex molecule and analyzing it as having a dative bond and 'normal' covalent bonds is bound to get you into trouble. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31003/7448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate covalent bonds are still counted as 1 electron, since the pair is shared between both atoms. That means the Carbon will have a formal charge of -1 and Oxygen a formal charge of +1 on Carbon Monoxide.

Carbon FC: $\ce{(4 valence electrons on neutral atom) - (1*2e- from lone pair + 3*1e- from covalent bonds) = -1}$

Oxygen FC: $\ce{(6 valence electrons on neutral atom) - (1*2e- from lone pair + 3*1e- from covalent bonds) = +1}$