# Bond order of carbon monoxide and nitrosyl cation

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, oxides

The following question was asked in JEE Mains exam in 2022, a competitive exam for engineering in India.

The difference between bond order of CO and NO$^+$ is $\frac{x}{2}$ where $x$ = ____. (Round off to the nearest integer).

Here, I have taken the bond order of CO as 2.6 (which is cited as the actual bond order of CO) as per:

1. [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/why-is-the-bond-order-of-co-3-5#:%7E:text=In%20short%3A%20The%20bond%20order,is%20stronger%20in%20CO%2B.) Stack Exchange answer
2. [Vocation India](https://www.vocationindia.com/the-bond-order-of-co-molecule-is/)
3. [Kayson Education](https://www.kaysonseducation.co.in/questions/p-span-sty_5387)
4. [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Transition-state-geometry-for-molecular-dissociation-channel_fig4_237274288)

and many other sources, the reason being the anti-bonding character in the non - bonding orbital in the Molecular Orbital diagram.

Upon solving we get:

$$3 - 2.6 = \frac{x}{2}\\
0.4 = \frac{x}{2}\\
x = 0.8\\
x = 1$$

But the answer given for said question is 0. They have taken the bond order of CO and NO$^+$, both as 3. So their solution is:

$$ 3 - 3 = \frac{x}{2}\\
0 = \frac{x}{2}\\
x = 0$$

On a technical level, the bond order of CO should be ~2.6, so my answer should be correct. Is the solution given wrong? The views of others on this topic would be welcome.

Comment: At this level they both have 3. If you want to nitpick it, then what makes you think NO cation would have effective bond order of 3 while CO doesn't?

Comment: Well, the difference between $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{NO+}$ is about a proton in the nucleus of nitrogen. They are isoelectric and at that level of approximation, that means they are basically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at this level you are supposed to make the simplifying assumption that bond order is $(1/2)×$(the number of electrons in bonding orbitals minus the number of electrons in antibonding orbitals); the $1/2$ coming from needing two electrons to make a bond. Ignore the "effective" bond order formalism on which the $2.6$ value for carbon monoxide is based (if we were to assess the "effective bond order" in the nitrosyl cation the same way that probably would also be less than $3.0$).

Here, you should verify that the molecular orbital structures for both species give eight bonding electrons and two antibonding ones, so a bond order of $(8-2)/2=3$ for both and that's where they get $x=0$.